# c# WindowsIdentity Impersonation Not working

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-identity

When I use WindowsIdentity Impersonation like this:

```
 WindowsIdentity newId = null;
        WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = null;

                 Console.WriteLine("Name of the identity BEFORE impersonation: "
   + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + ".");
                newId = new WindowsIdentity(_impersonationToken);
                impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
                Console.WriteLine("Name of the identity AFTER impersonation: "
    + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + ".");
```

(It's being used to copy files from my computer to a winCE machine.)

The Name Before and the Name after keep returning the same.
When I look @ the newId Token after the impersonation it isn't the same as the one I use to Impersonate with.
The Token I impersonate with is DEFINITELY not the same user as the one I'm logged in with.

Does anyone have any suggestions on why it does not want to use my token?
(ow yeah, Yesterday It worked like a charm :s)

This is how I generate my token:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);


LogonUser(Username, IPMachine, Password,
                            LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                            ref _token);
```

It give a successfull bool, so there is nothing wrong with my token i think

Comment: I got this working, but I cannot remember how I done it, sorry mate...

Comment: Ran into same problem. Do you, by any chance, remember the solution.

Comment: No i'm sorry, I didn't even remember it 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is another good example which you can try](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Windows/WindowsImpersonationContext.htm)

Comment: Now i understand the issue. You are running this program as user1 and probably you are providing the the same user (user1) credentials for impersonation and hence you cant see the difference. Try running the program as user1 and while running the program provide credentials of user2 for impersonation. You can see the difference. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx

Comment: I tried and it is working.             
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx

Comment: lol, why should I use the same credentials for impersonation? doens't that lose the intention of impersonation?? i'm definatly using other credentials, even in another domain (Zarkos = pc credentials, domain\blabla = impersonation credentials, ofcourse with a password)

Comment: When I try the MSDN thing u gave me it gives me a wrong username & password :s while my LogonUser doesn't give me that. The only diffrence is that the MSDN example uses SafeTokenHandle & I use IntPtr...

Comment: k, I got it to work the msdn version. But Before impersonation: Zarkos
After imptersonation: Zarkos
(impersonate user: Boemba)

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate your `_impersonationToken`?

There's an excellent solution regarding impersonation over at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx). Looking at that may give you some new ideas.

Comment: hi, thanks but unhelpfull. MSDN has a great example for using it, i copy past the whole thing and it was the same :(.

Answer (score 0):

I get this working:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Impersonate
/// </summary>
public class Impersonate
{
    #region "Class Members"
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonationContext;
    #endregion

    #region "Class Properties"
    private string domainName { get; set; }
    private string userName { get; set; }
    private string userPassword { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public Impersonate(string domainName, string userName, string userPassword)
    {
        this.domainName = domainName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    #region "Impersonation Code"
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public bool ImpersonateValidUser()
    {
        var token = IntPtr.Zero;
        var tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(this.userName, this.domainName, this.userPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    var tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                    _impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();

                    if (_impersonationContext != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(token);
                        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);

        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);

        return false;
    }

    public void UndoImpersonation()
    {
        _impersonationContext.Undo();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You can call it:

```
            var impessonate = new Impersonate(".", "User", "Psw");

            if (impessonate.ImpersonateValidUser())
            {
                // do stuff
                impessonate.UndoImpersonation();
            }
```